# How to count the number of options in select using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to compare the number of items in two select elements(HTML). I tried using length property(with jquery) but it always says that both select element have number of option =1. I am populating both the select elements dynamically. What to do?

```
      var $options=$("#test_select");
     $options.empty();
     $.each(t_test_list,function(index,value){
    $options.append($("<option>").text(value).attr("value",value));
     });

     var numdate=$("#date_select").length;
var numtest=$("#test_select").length;
alert(numdate);
alert(numtest);
if(numdate!=numtest)
    {
    alert("The number of dates do not match test cases!!!");
    }
```

Comment: it would be answerable if you post your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

Change:

```
var numdate=$("#date_select").length;
var numtest=$("#test_select").length;
```

to:

```
var numdate=$("#date_select").children('option').length;
var numtest=$("#test_select").children('option').length;
```

you need to get options length which are the children of select not the select length.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy  yes you are right. i should not answer it before he post his attempt.

Comment: @Awlad Liton It is good to see that you already knew what mistake would have been there :)

Comment: Just curious. Is there a reason you are using `$("#test_select").children('option')` instead of just `$('#date_select>option')`?